# How to create an array forEach of the playlist card ids on HTML landing page and assert order via Cypress

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, foreach, cypress

[image: HTML source:]

How to create an array forEach of the playlist card ids and test to assert array positioning/order on the page ex. 0=130, 1=100 etc. in Cypress

I think I could use this slector, but unsure how create forEach array for it...

```
data-object-type="playlists"
```

Test

```
it('verify expected order on program landing page', () =\> {

    cy.visit(learnerLandingPage);

});
```

I only tried asserting against the number of playlist cards present which work as expected, but unsure how/if I can use the playlists `data-object-type`

```
  cy.get('[data-object-type="playlists"]').should('have.length', 3);
```

Looking for the cleaneast way to accomplish with also being able to work across different environments where the ids in array will be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypress comes bundled with lodash so you can use the _.map() util to get only the values of each `data-object-type`.

The `data-object-type` should be unique and stable across environments. You will only need to know the expected values of each.

Here is a working [example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/blob/main/cypress/e2e/checkDataAttribute.md).

```js
const expectedOrder = ["130", "100", "1"];
cy.get("[data-object-type]")
  .should("have.length", 3)
  // get array of data-object-type attr
  .then(($list) =>
    Cypress._.map($list, ($el) => $el.getAttribute("data-object-type"))
  )
  .should("deep.equal", expectedOrder);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and sharing this. Unfortunately, I'm getting an assertion error -
expected [ Array(3) ] to deeply equal [ '1', '100', '130' ] and confirmed this is the expected order of the page... 

Update:

scratch that. I changed the getAttribute to data-object-id and is now working as expected. YTMND!

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way is using [cy.each()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each)

```js
const order = ['130', '100' , '1']

cy.get('[data-object-type="playlists"]').each(($el, index) => {
  expect($el.attr('data-object-id')).to.eq(order[index])
})
```

where `$el.attr('data-object-id')` uses jQuery to extract the id attribute.

---

An equivalent using `.invoke()` would be

```js
const order = ['130', '100' , '1']

cy.get('[data-object-type="playlists"]').each(($el, index) => {
  cy.wrap($el)
    .invoke('attr', 'data-object-id')
    .should('eq', order[index])
})
```

This has the advantage that `.should()` uses retry if the table is loaded asynchronously.